# Align <div>-s next to each other depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a responsive design layout but struggling to achieve something.

I want to make a gallery of photos that displays as much photos per line with a minimum width of 300px for each photo. Width should depend on screen size.

For example, iPhone screen would accommodate only 1 pic of this width, so it should display 1 photo per line which fills 100% screen width of iPhone screen and wrap the other photos into separate lines. I hope i'm clear enough.

Here is my code:

```
 <div style="width:100%;">

    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;">
         <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;">
         <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;">
         <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
    </div>

 </div>
```

Is this possible in pure CSS or it needs JS?

Comment: Do I get it right: photos with minimum with of 300px could mean: 

screen is 1200px wide containing 
image A with 600px and 
image B with 500px at the first row 
but image C with 300px would float down to next line? 

Most answers pretend each column to be 33% no matter of image size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;float:left">
     <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;float:left">
     <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;width:32%;float:left">
     <img style="min-width:300px;max-width:100%;" src="/images/test.png" />
</div>
```

Once you float you never go back.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. just teated on my iPhone. All the boxes would become small to fit one line and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

[`float`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the div's should work:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/2CN6B/. Click the Grow and Shrink buttons to see if this is what you want.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    float: left;
}

#container {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}
```

Comment: So you gave a fixed width to the container just for the test? I think the container should be 100%. Also is there any way to avoid the clear fix?

Comment: Yes, the fixed width for the container was for test, for simulating varying screen sizes. The Grow and Shrink buttons change the container width to simulate different screen widths (or resizing of browser windows)

Comment: Is there a way to make the image fill the width of the container? For example if the screen width is 400px then it will accommodate only 1 image, can i get the image to become 400px wide to fill the screen?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Are you looking to scale images?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Media Queries are helpful for you to differ between large screens and small ones.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
    <img src="/images/test.png"/>
</div>
```

and Stylesheet

```
img{
/* position as many at one line as possible */
    float: left;
    min-width:300px
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
/* handle small screens */
    img{
        width: 100;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

more info at [css-tricks.com: CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Media querys, and scale up images to the right % depending on how many of then can de hold in a line with your minimum width requirement.

@ max-width 300 (or so); img width 100%

@ 300 to 600 { img width 50% }

@ 600 to 900 { img width 33% }

...and so on...

and finaly:
img min-width:300px;